# How do I save related objects in many to many relationships?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have the following schema definition:

```
Usuario:
 columns:
  empresa_id:     { type: BIGINT, notnull: true }
  direccion_id:   { type: BIGINT, notnull: false }
  publicidad_id:  { type: BIGINT, notnull: true }
  tipo_id:        { type: BIGINT, notnull: true }
  nombre:         { type: string(60), notnull: true }
  paterno:        { type: string(60), notnull: true }
  materno:        { type: string(60), notnull: true }
  curp:           { type: string(20), notnull: false }
  rfc:            { type: string(13), notnull: false }
  correoPrincipal:  { type: string(100), notnull: true, unique: true }
  correoSecundario: { type: string(100), notnull: false, unique: true }
  telefonoFijo:   { type: string(12), notnull: true }
  telefonoMovil:  { type: string(12), notnull: false }
  validado:       { type: boolean, notnull: false, default: false }
  usuario:        { type: string(10), notnull: false }
  password:       { type: string(10), notnull: false }
  matricula:      { type: string(16), notnull: false }
  fechaNacimiento: { type: date, notnull: true }
 relations:
  Direccion:  { onDelete: CASCADE, local: direccion_id, foreign: id }
  Empresa:    { onDelete: CASCADE, local: empresa_id, foreign: id, class: Empresa }
  Publicidad: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: publicidad_id, foreign: id }
  Tipo:       { onDelete: CASCADE, local: tipo_id, foreign: id, class: conamatTipo }
  Bachillerato:
    class: Bachillerato
    refClass: BachilleratoUsuario
    local: usuario_id
    foreign: bachillerato_id
    foreignAlias: Usuarios
  UsuarioSede:
    class: Sede
    refClass: SedeUsuario
    local: usuario_id
    foreign: sede_id
    foreignAlias: Usuario
SedeUsuario:
  columns:
    sede_id: { type: bigint, notnull: true }
    usuario_id: { type: bigint, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Usuario: { local: usuario_id, foreign: id }
    Sede: { local: sede_id, foreign: id }
```

How can I make a form that lets me add multiple "sedes" to one "usuario", I've tried the advanced forms chapter in the symfony documentation, but I don't want to embed the form, I want to use it as another form all alone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Doctrine in a recent version (I don't know since when this exists), you relationships will be saved when a related object is saved, assuming it the relation has changed. This work without embedded forms (even without form), it's a different thing and part of the ORM.

If this behavior does not work, it's an issue with your model declaration in schema.yml